# FourSquare API To Pull Reviews?

Tags: foursquare

Does the Foursquare API allow us to pull reviews and then allowing the verified location to respond to it?
I am just wondering if the API allows access to reviews and pulling those sets of data.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, but this is a question that can be answered  by reading the  documentation. Please come back when you have written Foursquare  API  code that you think should be pulling reviews but isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foursquare doesn't have reviews per se. They call them tips, and you can get them via the API for a specific venue or user -> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips